# How to Pass parameters to SSRS report from VB.net using webrowser control

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, webbrowser-control

I am writing a application using VB 2017. I have put webBrowser control on form. The report is displaying correctly but I have not been able to populate the parameters into report and then render the report to display. I can manually select the values for parameters once the report is displayed. There are 3 parameter with the first being a date, the second null value and the third is a text value

Here is how I am calling the report now.

```
    Dim url As String = "http://myServer/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fPicking+Reports%2fSHIFT+MGMT+-+Status+Summary+by+Picks&rs:command=Render&DelDate=10/8/2019&routenull:isnull=true&EstimateBy=Target+Pick+Rate"
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(url)
```

My question is two fold. What am I doing wrong as none of the parameter values are showing. Secondly how would go about compressing the toolbars on top of screen.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing any parameters to the report via the URL. Add the parameters after the `command` section of the URL, replacing with your parameter names and values of course:

```
:Parameters=false&MyParameter=ABC123
```

**EDIT: Using your parameter information, try this. I've broken it up just for readability here.**

```
Dim url As String = "http://myServer/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fPicking+Reports%2fSHIFT+MGMT+-+Status+Summary+by+Picks&rs"
url &= ":command=Render&rc"
url &= ":Parameters=false&Deldate=10/8/2019&Routenull:isnull=true&EstimateBy=Target+Pick+Rate"
```

Note that you can create cleaner URL Strings, per this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/pass-a-report-parameter-within-a-url?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-previousversions

Comment: Not exactly sure where the parameters would go. In my original post I do have parameters after the command. I have now tried using the :parameters=false and still not luck. What is wrong with the original line or this line.                    http://Reportserver/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fPickRight+Reports%2fSHIFT+MGMT+-+Status+Summary+by+Picks&rs:command=Render&:parameters=false&DelDate=10/8/2019&routenull=null&EstimateBy=Target+Pick+Rate&rc:Toolbar=false

Comment: What are all of your parameters and test values? Trying to parse that URL with the eye is not easy.

Comment: parameter1 is Deldate equaled to 10/8/2019. Parameter2 is Routenull equal to null. parameter3 is EstimateBy equal to Target Pick Rate. with the spaces changed to +